# Memory Models and Concurrency

Tags: c++, c, memory, concurrency, memory-model

I wanted to know about C/C++ memory model but I found in all of the articles, blogs, youtube videos that "Memory models are only needed for concurrency"..

Can anyone please clarify to me why is this the case?

I understand that a memory model is an abstraction that allows the programmer to reason about the underlying memory system using a programming language (correct?) so generally speaking (independent of the programming language) don't we still need memory models for single threaded programs?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  A question like this, especially when tagged with both [tag:c] and [tag:c++], is simply too broad to be answerable on SO.  It would take a lot of explanation; books have been written on the topic.  And there are major differences between C and C++, especially in what's actually implemented compared with what the standard says might be implemented by a conforming implementation.

Comment: Perhaps https://www.amazon.co.uk/Inside-Object-Model-Stanley-Lippman/dp/0201834545

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think the answer is the same irrespective of the language. It's a question at a more fundamental level. So I don't think it's broad. The OP probably used the C and C++ tags because they were expecting that those communities would be able to answer the question.

Comment: The term *memory model* is used in different ways depending on the context. I think the OP think it's the [memory addressing model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address#Memory_models).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that a memory model is an abstraction that allows the
>   programmer to reason about the underlying memory system using a
>   programming language (correct?)

A memory consistency model is a set of rules that allows the programmer to reason about the possible states of the program at any point in time during its execution from the perspective of each individual agent (core) that is accessing the state, if certain conditions were satisfied (such as no data races).

> I wanted to know about C/C++ memory model but I found in all of the
>   articles, blogs, youtube videos that "Memory models are only needed
>   for concurrency"..
>
> Can anyone please clarify to me why is this the case?

There are some rules that can be considered as part of the memory model that would also apply in the context of single threaded programs. In particular:

- A read that follows a write to the same location will read the value written, not an older value.
- A write that follows another write to the same location will overwrite the previously written value.
- A write that follows a read to the same location will only modify the location after the read completes.

However, these rules are considered to be so fundamental and intuitive that it is not worth stating them in every memory model. In case of VLIW architectures, the compiler automatically follows these rules. In case of traditional architectures, both the compiler (according to the order of the statements in the source code) and the processor follow these rules (according to the order of the instruction stream). So basically it's redundant to state them. Other than that, there are no other useful rules for single-threaded programs.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that memory model doesn't apply to single threaded code is that in ST code you execute one statement after another and there is no possibility of mix-up. In multi-threaded code it is possible for an object's value to change without warning to the current thread. The memory model concept lets you ensure that particular statements execute after all other threads have finished updating a value or that a particular statement executes before any other thread reads the object's value.

Answer (score 1):

this is a cite from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_(programming)

> A memory model allows a compiler to perform many important optimizations. Compiler optimizations like loop fusion move statements in the program, which can influence the order of read and write operations of potentially shared variables. Changes in the ordering of reads and writes can cause race conditions.

The compiler can change the order of read and write of variables, and still guarantee the code fragment will run as if the read/writes are done sequentially. however if multi-threading is involved, this can cause problems, as reading/writing of variables, not at the code order, may cause multi-threaded related problems.

examine the following code which is executed by 2 threads, both use the same variables init and value:

```
static int init = 0;
static int value = 0;

thread_a:
while( !init )
    Sleep( 100 );
    if ( value == 100 )
        do something ...

thread_b:
    value = 100;
    init = 1;
```

the compiler may run the code for thread_b in different order (or in parallel) causing init to be set to 1 before value is set to 100. when working with single thread, this has no signifcant, however, when having multiple threads examining this variables, this can cause a problem. and here the memory model comes to solve this problems.

Answer (score 1):

What is generally referred to as *memory model* refers to the interaction of different threads of execution accessing objects. In this sense it is entirely tied to concurrency. It isn’t reall about memory.

There is another important aspect which is referred to as *object model* and [Stan Lippman’s book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Inside-Object-Model-Stanley-Lippman/dp/0201834545) is an excellent resource for learning about that (it is a bit dated but stays mostly relevant). The object model also doesn’t really talk about how memory is accessed.

The closest to a description of how memory is accessed in general is Ulrich Drepper’s [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory_](https://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf). This artivle is about the general view of memory, independent of programming languages. Of course, depending on the object model different programming languages may hide direct interaction with memory.